# FeedForward Neural Network: Using a single Network with multiple output neurons for many classes

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation, feed-forward

I am currently working on the MNIST handwritten digits classification.

I built a single FeedForward network with the following structure:

- **Inputs:** 28x28 = 784 inputs
- **Hidden Layers:** A single hidden layer with 1000 neurons
- **Output Layer:** 10 neurons

All the neurons have **Sigmoid** activation function.

**The reported class is the one corresponding to the output neuron with the maximum output value**

My questions are:

- Is it a good approach to create a single network with multiple outputs? I.e. should I instead create a separated network per each digit?

I ask about it, as currently **the network is stuck on ~75% success rate**. As the actually "10 classifiers" share the same neurons of the hidden layer - I am not sure - does it reduce the network learning capability?

** EDIT: **

As other people may take reference of this thread, I want to be honest and update that the 75% success rate was after ~1500 epochs. Now I'm after nearly 3000 epochs and it's on ~85% of success rate - so it works pretty well

Comment: You should use a softmax layer for the output, not a sigmoid.

Comment: What is "softmax" layer? Do you mean linear when saying "softmax"?

Comment: No, I mean softmax when I say softmax: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function

Comment: I first tried with linear output layer and I got too high values (I want 0/1 answers - so I preferred to use function that is bounded between 0/1)

Comment: look at the link I posted. You should use neither a liner, nor a sigmoid, you should use a soft-max, which is what is used for multi-class classification.

Comment: @AndreasMueller If he/she is not doing multi-class classification, is there any benefit to using softmax over just selecting the greatest sigmoid output value?

Comment: @bogatron this is what I actually did. What is the aim of "softmax"? Does it enable multiclass with one output neuron? When is it better to use "softmax" over multiple output neurons (a neuron for each class)?

Comment: No, softmax still has multiple output neurons (one for each class) but the outputs are normalized (and sum to 1) so they can be interpreted as probabilities for each class. My question was whether this provides any improvement in classification over what you did if you only care about the most probable class.

Comment: yes, it does, and you should always use it. It is not only an activation function, it is also related to the loss function. When I mean "soft-max", I mean an output layer with soft-max activation and log-loss. Look at wikipedia or any introduction to neural nets. I imagine you are currently using squared loss with sigmoid, which is not great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes it is a good approach to use a single network with multiple outputs. The first hidden layer describes decision boundaries (hyperplanes) in your feature space and multiple digits can benefit from some of the same hyperplanes. While you could create one ANN for each digit, that kind of one-vs-rest approach doesn't necessarily yield better results and requires training 10 times as many ANNs (each of which might be trained multiple times to try to avoid local minima). If you had hundreds or thousands of digits, then it might make more sense.

1000 neurons in a single hidden layer seems like a lot for this problem. I think you would probably achieve better results for handwritten digits by reducing that number and adding a second hidden layer. That would let you model more complex combinations boundaries in the input feature space. For example, perhaps try something like a `784x20x20x10` network.

If you do experiment with different network structures, it is usually better to start with a smaller number of layers & neurons and then increase complexity. That not only reduces training time but also avoids overfitting the data right away (you didn't mention if your accuracy was for a training or validation set).

Comment: The key word to add here is "features". The reason we're using features is that using every single pixel as input is both an overkill and unnecessary noise. Every successful approach has some sort of dimensionality reduction (inducing data abstraction), take e.g. CNNs. It's not *just* all about adding more layers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can surely use a single network with multiple outputs. Creating separate network is not required and your approach will in no way reduce the network learning capability. The MNIST is a handwritten database suitable for Deep Learning. So adding multiple layers is a good solution provided you are using Deep Learning algorithms. Otherwise adding multiple layers with simple BPN based models is not advisable as you will run into local minima's. You can look up on Theano for a Deep Learning tutorial. 
That being said you can try simple logistic regression "deeplearning.net/tutorial/logreg.html" and it achieves quite a good accuracy.